# how to count duplicates values inside while loop using php

Tags: php, count

$query = "select * from tableitem";
$result = mysql_query($query);

```
$col = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

 //they have computation here inside loop.
  $amount = $value;

if($row['status']>3){  // base on the status only
    if($amount>0){ //base on the computation 

        $count = $item;
        // i need to count here the item before the grouping of duplicate item below.

    if (!isset($col[$row['item']])) { // this is working for grouping the duplicate value
       echo $row['item'];  
       echo $count;   // count item 
       $col[$row['item']] = true;
      }
   }
 }}
```

Sample output should be like this inside while loop if possible.

Item one  2
Item two  3
Item five  4

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with sql not necessary php;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as N,item 
FROM tableitem
GROUP BY item
```

it will return duplicate items and you can check with `n>1`. And you can add more column for group.

```
$itemArray;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($row['n']>1){
       itemArray[] = $row['item'];    
    }    
}
print_r($itemArray);
```

Comment: tnkyou hurricane but im sorry to include that i have computation inside loop. so based on the computation and conditon thats only the time i count the item.

Answer (score 0):

If you increment array values using the keys you are trying to count:

```
$check = array();
foreach($values as $key => $value) {
   if (isset($check[$key])) {
       $check[$key]++;
   } else {
       $check[$key]=1;
   }
}
var_dump($check);
```

Comment: thnks nicholas. im trying to count the item base on the codition above